# Dynamically set External dns for EKS fargate ingress alb using external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, external-dns

I am trying to set up external dns from Eks manifest file.

I created EKS cluster and created 3 fargate profiles, default, kube-system and dev.
Coredns pods are up and running.

I then installed AWS Load Balancer Controller by following this doc.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html
The  load  balancer controller came up in kube-system.

I then  installed external-dns deployment using the following manifest file.

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ServiceAccount
    metadata:
      name: external-dns
      namespace: kube-system
      annotations:
         eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/eks-externaldnscontrollerRole-XST756O4A65B
    ---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: external-dns
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services"]
  verbs: ["get","watch","list"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get","watch","list"]
- apiGroups: ["extensions"]
  resources: ["ingresses"]
  verbs: ["get","watch","list"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["nodes"]
  verbs: ["list"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: external-dns-viewer
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: external-dns
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: external-dns
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: external-dns
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: external-dns
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: external-dns
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: external-dns
      containers:
      - name: external-dns
        image: bitnami/external-dns:0.7.1
        args:
        - --source=service
        - --source=ingress
        #- --domain-filter=xxxxxxxxxx.com # will make ExternalDNS see only the hosted zones matching provided domain, omit to process all available hosted zones
        - --provider=aws
        #- --policy=upsert-only # would prevent ExternalDNS from deleting any records, omit to enable full synchronization
        - --aws-zone-type=public # only look at public hosted zones (valid values are public, private or no value for both)
        - --registry=txt
        - --txt-owner-id=my-identifier
      #securityContext:
      #  fsGroup: 65534
```

I used both namespace kube-system and dev for external-dns, both came up fine.

I then deployed, the application and  ingress  manifest files. I used both namespaces, kube-system and dev.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1-nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: app1-nginx
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app1-nginx
          image: kube-nginxapp1:1.0.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
            limits:
              memory: "500Mi"
              cpu: "1000m"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1-nginx-nodeport-service
  labels:
    app: app1-nginx
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
#Important Note:  Need to add health check path annotations in service level if we are planning to use multiple targets in a load balancer
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /app1/index.html
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: app1-nginx
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80


----------

# Annotations Reference:  https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/ingress/annotation/
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-usermgmt-restapp-service
  labels:
    app: usermgmt-restapp
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    # Ingress Core Settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    # Health Check Settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: traffic-port
    #Important Note:  Need to add health check path annotations in service level if we are planning to use multiple targets in a load balancer
    #alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /usermgmt/health-status
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '15'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds: '5'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: '200'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count: '2'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count: '2'
    ## SSL Settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}, {"HTTP":80}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:0xxxxxxxxxx:certificate/0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    #alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-1-2017-01 #Optional (Picks default if not used)
    # SSL Redirect Setting
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    # External DNS - For creating a Record Set in Route53
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: palb.xxxxxxx.com
    # For Fargate
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /* # SSL Redirect Setting
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: ssl-redirect
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
          - path: /*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: app1-nginx-nodeport-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

All  pods came up fine but  it is not dynamically registering the  the dns alias for thr alb.
Can you please guide me to know what i am  going wrong?

---

Answer (score 1):

First, check the ingress itself works. Check the AWS load balancers and load balancer target groups. The target group targets should be active.
If you do a `kubectl get ingress` this should be also output the DNS name of the load balancer created.
Use `curl` to check this url works!
The annotation `external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: palb.xxxxxxx.com` does not work for ingresses. It is only valid for services. But you don't need it. Just specify the `host` field for the ingress `spec.rules`. In your example there is no such property. Specify it!